# Multiple values for argument writing elan file

Tags: python

I'm using `Exploface` following [this tutorial](https://github.com/emrecdem/exploface/blob/master/TUTORIALS/tutorial1.ipynb) with no problems except the 4th point: "Writing out an Elan file using Exploface".

This is provided in the tutorial:

```py
dataframe_timestamp = exploface.write_elan_file(
    feature_detections,
    video_path=video_file,
    output_path="video.eaf",
)
```

What I'm trying is:

```py
dataframe_timestamp = exploface.write_elan_file(
    'frame', 
    'timestamp', 
    'confidence',
    video_path=video_file,
    output_path="C:\\Users\\fullname\\Desktop",
)
```

Also tried:

```py
dataframe_timestamp = exploface.write_elan_file(
    'frame', 
    'timestamp', 
    'confidence',
    video_path=video_file,
    output_path="C:\\Users\\fullname\\Desktop\\output.eaf",
)
```

And I also tried to point it to the original video

```py
dataframe_timestamp = exploface.write_elan_file(
    'frame', 
    'timestamp', 
    'confidence',
    video_path="C:\\Users\\fullname\\Desktop\\originalvideo.mp4",
    output_path="C:\\Users\\fullname\\Desktop\\output.eaf",
)
```

It is supposed to create the elan file but it's giving this error message:

```sh
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: write_elan_file() got multiple values for argument 
'video_path'
```

Comment: Try `video_path="C:\Users\fullname\Desktop\originalvideo.mp4"` or `video_path="C:/Users/fullname/Desktop/originalvideo.mp4"`

Comment: @codrelphi, the first one gives `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape` because it attempts to decode `\Users` as a Unicode escape, but fails because such an escape is invalid

Answer (score 0):

The error is about your *code*, not the data you feed into the function, so all three last examples are identical from this point of view.

The problem is that `video_path="whatever"` attempts to pass some value as an argument called `video_path`, but one of the *positional* arguments does the same thing:

```
dataframe_timestamp = exploface.write_elan_file(
    'frame',  # from the tutorial we know that this is NOT the `video_path` argument
    'timestamp',   # the second positional argument may be called `video_path`
    'confidence',   # the third positional argument may be called `video_path`

    video_path=video_file,

    ...
)
```

So, according to the error message, one of the three *positional* arguments is called `video_path`, yet you're referring to the same argument as a *keyword argument* with `video_path=video_file`. So, there are multiple values (one of `'timestamp'` and `'confidence'` as well as `video_file`) for the same argument `video_path`.

To solve this, look up the signature of this function in the docs or with `help(exploface.write_elan_file)` and see what kind of arguments the function expects and note their positions.

---

Here's a simpler piece of code that has the same issue:

```
>>> def hello(name):
...  print(f"Hello, {name}!")
... 
>>> hello("Skyandlow")
Hello, Skyandlow!
>>> hello("Skyandlow", name="ForceBru")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: hello() got multiple values for argument 'name'
>>>
```

The call `hello("Skyandlow", name="ForceBru")` attempts to pass `"Skyandlow"` as the first argument (which is called `name`, as one can see from the definition of the function) and `"ForceBru"` as the argument called `name`. This makes no sense because we're thus passing *two values* as the same argument `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the Exploface repo and the function `write_elan_file` is defined as below.

```py
# exploface/__init__.py

def write_elan_file(detections,
                    output_path=None,
                    video_path=None,
                    #column_selection = None,
                    ):
    """
    Generates an Elan file for the detections

    """
    elanwriter.write_elan_file(detections, video_path, output_path,
        feature_col_name = _FEAT_NAME_ID)
```

The error of your question is produced because you are passing too many arguments to the function, which only accepts 3.